# Compare two files based on the condition using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have two files:

1.txt:

```
j_e_s_s_i_c_a_a_n_n zoltan670605@freemail.hu  61b8a203438ea1c56c1489ec7bea7a0e
9871951 sexbollente@hotmail.com 671cb9239bf797a082f723a07a9c713f
holliebrian nnagle1@yahoo.com a2e531ea7df55290c35d74082f38f020
9075407 car_jacko@hotmail.fr  d20f83ee6933aa1ea047fe5cbd9c1fd5
9837056 alainkp@gmail.com e4d11b1c62cfbb7bfb49e4644e70d476
```

2.txt:

```
a2e531ea7df55290c35d74082f38f020:182:@*/
671cb9239bf797a082f723a07a9c713f:1199
e4d11b1c62cfbb7bfb49e4644e70d476:abcd123
d20f83ee6933aa1ea047fe5cbd9c1fd5:33;1:11
```

I want the two files as output:
One is left.txt in which that lines of 1.txt will be there whose 3rd column (FS = ' ')  does not match with second column of 2.txt (FS = ':')

left.txt:

```
j_e_s_s_i_c_a_a_n_n zoltan670605@freemail.hu  61b8a203438ea1c56c1489ec7bea7a0e
```

Another file is result.txt in which all the lines from 1.txt which contains a match in 2.txt. But in the output file the matched 3rd column should be replaced by the matched line 2nd column (FS = ':')

result.txt:

```
9871951 sexbollente@hotmail.com 1199
holliebrian nnagle1@yahoo.com 182:@*/
9075407 car_jacko@hotmail.fr 33;1:11
9837056 alainkp@gmail.com abcd123
```

I wrote a script to achieve the same task:

```
awk -F : 'FNR==NR {s=$0;sub(/[^:]*:/, "", s); p[$1]=s; next} !($NF in p) {print > "left.txt"; next} {$NF=p[$NF]} 1' 2.txt FS=' ' OFS=' ' <(tr -d '\r' < 1.txt) > result.txt
```

I am getting the expected output but on bigger files 1.txt (~ 3GB) and 2.txt (~ 1 GB). The script is crashing with the following error:

> awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=2.txt FNR=21085923) fatal:
>   /home/corinna/src/gawk/gawk-4.2.0/gawk-4.2.0-1.x86_64/src/gawk-4.2.0/node.c:1021:more_blocks:
>   freep: can't allocate 9600 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)

Please help me to make the script run for bigger files. Any help would be highly appreciated. Using awk is not must. The only motto is to do the right job in lesser time and without crashing.

Comment: i think it's better sort by column like 61b8a203438ea1c56c1489ec7bea7a0e, than  you will handle with these files line by line.

Comment: I don't think that's gonna work. Sorting may take more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  val=$1;
  sub(/[^:]*/,"");
  sub(/:/,"");
  a[val]=$0;
  next
}
!($NF in a){
  print > "left.txt";
  next
}
{
  print $1,$2,a[$NF]> "result.txt"
}
'  FS=":" 2.txt FS=" "  OFS=" " 1.txt
```

Comment: What about result.txt ?

Comment: The output of result.txt is different than I mentioned above. The left.txt is correct.

Comment: The output was posted earlier the same. I just edited to write my script to show what I have done so far.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, please try my edited code and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: It is producing the same output but the problem is you are using array and it may throw memory allocation error on larger files.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, not sure as I don't have big size files(though I believe it should work properly only). Can you check and  let us know, since you have mentioned you have big size files?

Comment: Yes I am checking.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, sure, I strongly believe it should pass, let us know how it goes then.

Comment: ./my.sh line 16: 5852 Killed awk'    . This is the error I got this time.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, not sure it is working well and fine for me. Check the process in backend `ps -ef` while it is running, check either a single file created or not, also what o.s you are using(use `nawk` for sun o.s)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089352/merge-two-files-using-awk-in-linux, can you please check it ?