# Merge two files using awk in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a 1.txt file:

```
betomak@msn.com||o||0174686211||o||7880291304ca0404f4dac3dc205f1adf||o||Mario||o||Mario||o||Kawati
zizipi@libero.it||o||174732943.0174732943||o||e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e||o||Tiziano||o||Tiziano||o||D'Intino
frankmel@hotmail.de||o||0174844404||o||8d496ce08a7ecef4721973cb9f777307||o||Melanie||o||Melanie||o||Kiesel
apoka-paris@hotmail.fr||o||0174847613||o||536c1287d2dc086030497d1b8ea7a175||o||Sihem||o||Sihem||o||Sousou
sofianomovic@msn.fr||o||174902297.0174902297||o||9893ac33a018e8d37e68c66cae23040e||o||Nabile||o||Nabile||o||Nassime
donaldduck@yahoo.com||o||174912161.0174912161||o||0c770713436695c18a7939ad82bc8351||o||Donald||o||Donald||o||Duck
cernakova@centrum.cz||o||0174991962||o||d161dc716be5daf1649472ddf9e343e6||o||Dagmar||o||Dagmar||o||Cernakova
trgsrl@tiscali.it||o||0175099675||o||d26005df3e5b416d6a39cc5bcfdef42b||o||Esmeralda||o||Esmeralda||o||Trogu
catherinesou@yahoo.fr||o||0175128896||o||2e9ce84389c3e2c003fd42bae3c49d12||o||Cat||o||Cat||o||Sou
ermimurati24@hotmail.com||o||0175228687||o||a7766a502e4f598c9ddb3a821bc02159||o||Anna||o||Anna||o||Beratsja
cece_89@live.fr||o||0175306898||o||297642a68e4e0b79fca312ac072a9d41||o||Celine||o||Celine||o||Jacinto
kendinegel39@hotmail.com||o||0175410459||o||a6565ca2bc8887cde5e0a9819d9a8ee9||o||Adem||o||Adem||o||Bulut
```

A 2.txt file:

```
9893ac33a018e8d37e68c66cae23040e:134:@a1
536c1287d2dc086030497d1b8ea7a175:~~@!:/92\
8d496ce08a7ecef4721973cb9f777307:demodemo
```

FS for 1.txt is "||o||" and for 2.txt is ":"
I want to merge two files in a single file result.txt based on the condition that the 3rd column of 1.txt must match with 1st column of 2.txt file and should be replaced by the 2nd column of 2.txt file.

The expected output will contain all the matching lines:
I am showing you one of them:

```
sofianomovic@msn.fr||o||174902297.0174902297||o||134:@a1||o||Nabile||o||Nabile||o||Nassime
```

I tried the script:

```
awk -F"||o||"  'NR==FNR{s=$0; sub(/:[^:]*$/, "", s); a[s]=$NF;next} {s = $5; for (i=6; i<=NF; ++i) s = s "," $i; if (s in a) { NF = 5; $5=a[s]; print } }' FS=: <(tr -d '\r' < 2.txt) FS="||o||" OFS="||o||" <(tr -d '\r' < 1.txt) > result.txt
```

But getting an empty file as the result. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to backslash the pipe in the `-F` argument because it is treated as a regex. On MacOS I get "illegal primary in regular expression" with this `-F` argument.

Comment: You get an award for the craziest ad-hoc file format so far today. Are you *really* unable to find a better way to separate your columns?

Comment: 2nd column value is `134` but your expected output shows `134@a1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actual Input_file(s) are same as shown sample then following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -v s1="||o||" '
FNR==NR{
  a[$9]=$1 s1 $5;
  b[$9]=$13 s1 $17 s1 $21;
  next
}
($1 in a){
  print a[$1] s1 $2 FS $3 s1 b[$1]
}
' FS="|" 1.txt FS=":" 2.txt
```

***EDIT:*** Since OP has changed requirement a bit so providing code as per new ask where it will create 2 files too 1 file which will have ids present in 1.txt and NOT in 2.txt and other will be vice versa of it.

```
awk -v s1="||o||" '
FNR==NR{
  a[$9]=$1 s1 $5;
  b[$9]=$13 s1 $17 s1 $21;
  c[$9]=$0;
  next
}
($1 in a){
  val=$1;
  $1="";
  sub(/:/,"");
  print a[val] s1 $0 s1 b[val];
  d[val]=$0;
  next
}
{
  print > "NOT_present_in_2.txt"
}
END{
for(i in d){
  delete c[i]
};
for(j in c){
  print j,c[j] > "NOT_present_in_1.txt"
}}
' FS="|" 1.txt FS=":" OFS=":" 2.txt
```

Comment: what is s1="||o||" doing?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, I had taken it as a variable `-v variable=value`, this is how we define variables in a `awk` script/code.

Comment: I need a left.txt in which all the lines of 1.txt will be there which have no match in 2.txt , can you modify the script accordingly ?

Comment: frankmel@hotmail.de||o||0174844404||o||demodemo:||o||Melanie||o||Melanie||o||Kiesel    Why I am getting demodemo: in the output, though there is no ':' at the end of demodemo in 2.txt ?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, it is not good to change your requirements in post, please try to post questions in a single shot itself. Let me look into it and update it accordingly then.

Comment: Sorry for updating it later. Also there is a bug in the script you have written as I have updated in the comments.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, for your `demodemo:` as I mentioned before since I am writing field numbers there in code so in case a field is less in a line it will print :, let me look on to it.

Comment: The script you gave me here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059139/compare-two-files-based-on-the-condition-using-awk may work , only the field separators are changed I guess. Let's see if if helps you because I am not getting it.

Comment: Or you can make another one for left.txt and fix the bug in this one for result.txt. depends on you. Thanks for the help, you are awesome :)

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, please do not ask updates on site, this is a site to help and guide people. All are helping and learning for each other. Please check my EDIT code now and let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The script got killed. ./my.sh line23: 18491 Killed

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, could you please use `set -x` before script and try to run it, make sure you are copying entire script as it is running fine for me(with sample provided data).

Comment: I have 13 GB of 1.txt and 3 GB of 2.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` to get your output:

```
awk -F ':' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3; next} FNR==1{FS=OFS="||o||"; gsub(/[|]/, "\\\\&", FS)}
$3 in a{$3=a[$3]; print}' file2 file1 > result.txt

cat result.txt
frankmel@hotmail.de||o||0174844404||o||demodemo:||o||Melanie||o||Melanie||o||Kiesel
apoka-paris@hotmail.fr||o||0174847613||o||~~@!:/92\||o||Sihem||o||Sihem||o||Sousou
sofianomovic@msn.fr||o||174902297.0174902297||o||134:@a1||o||Nabile||o||Nabile||o||Nassime
```