# Matching files using awk in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have 2 files:

1.txt:

```
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
f8b46e989c5794eec4e268605b63eb59
e3ceb5881a0a1fdaad01296d7554868d
```

2.txt:

```
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e:1111
679ab793796da4cbd0dda3d0daf74ec1:1234
f8b46e989c5794eec4e268605b63eb59:1@/233:
```

I want 2 files as output:
One is result.txt which contains lines from 2.txt whose match is in 1.txt 
and another is left.txt which contains lines from 1.txt whose match is not in 2.txt

Expected output of both files is below:
result.txt

```
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e:1111
f8b46e989c5794eec4e268605b63eb59:1@/233:
```

left.txt

```
e3ceb5881a0a1fdaad01296d7554868d
```

I tried 1-2 approaches with awk but not succeeded. Any help would be highly appreciated.

My script:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  val=$1;
  sub(/[^:]*/,"");
  sub(/:/,"");
  a[val]=$0;
  next
}
!($NF in a){
  print > "left.txt";
  next
}
{
  print $1,$2,a[$NF]> "result.txt"
}
'  FS=":" 2.txt FS=":"  OFS=":" 1.txt
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: With the answers to your last two questions ([Merge two files using awk in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089352/merge-two-files-using-awk-in-linux) and [Compare two files based on the condition using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059139/compare-two-files-based-on-the-condition-using-awk)) you should be able to do it yourself.

Comment: I had deleted my post(which was posted near to Cyrus comment time vice), please answer Cyrus question will re-post it then.

Comment: I tried to learn from my last 2 posts, but the scripts are very complex so I am unable to understand them. I posted the simple problem now so that I can learn from it. Thanks :)

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, fair enough, I added explanation into my answer now, please try to learn from it and other answers as we all are here to improve and learn, cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($0 in a){print a[$0] > "results.txt";next} {print > "left.txt"}' FS=":" OFS=":" 2.txt FS=" " OFS=":" 1.txt
```

***EDIT:*** Adding explanation of code too here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{    ##FNR==NR condition will be TRUE when first Input_file is being read by awk. Where FNR and NR are the out of the box variables for awk.
  a[$1]=$0; ##creating an array named a whose index is $1 and value is $2 from 2.txt Input_file.
  next      ##next is out of the box keyword from awk and will skip all further statements of awk.
}
($0 in a){  ##Checking here condition if current line of Input_file 1.txt is present in array named a then do following.
  print a[$0] > "results.txt"; ##Printing the current line into output file named results.txt, since current line is coming in array named a(which was created by 1st file).
  next      ##next is awk keyword which will skip further statements for awk code now.
}
{
  print > "left.txt" ##Printing all lines which skip above condition(which means they did not come into array a) to output file named left.txt as per OP need.
}
' FS=":" OFS=":" 2.txt FS=" " OFS=":" 1.txt ##Setting FS(field separator) as colon for 2.txt and Setting FS to space for 1.txt here. yes, we could set multiple field separators for different Input_file(s).
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) But your output of results.txt is not matching with my output of result.txt

Comment: e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e 1111
f8b46e989c5794eec4e268605b63eb59 1@/233
Still not matching the desired output.    left.txt is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I also solved 2 other problems myself. Now the concept is completely understood to me.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, glad that it helped you. Keep sharing, keep learning, cheers :)

Comment: The script is not working for bigger files like 3 GB file. :(

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, are you getting some error? Please always mention complete details for your issue. Let me know on same.

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!d6hVRaLD!QComyNlNlX0lKxcgt4PS_4JoQ2aqGU8g_t82vgAfCk4  The larger files are at this link. I am getting only left.txt in this case.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, people monitor the `awk` and other TAG queue(s) you need not to update the old posts, please delete above comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = ":" }NR==FNR{ a[$0]; next }$1 in a{ print $0 > "results.txt"; delete a[$1]; next }END{ for ( i in a ) print i > "left.txt" }' 1.txt 2.txt
```

Output:

results.txt

```
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e:1111
f8b46e989c5794eec4e268605b63eb59:1@/233:
```

left.txt

```
e3ceb5881a0a1fdaad01296d7554868d
```